# Android backup/restore - complete clone, including settings

Tags: gratis, android, backup

I damaged my phone, got a new one and found that my restore was only partial - apps, contacts, photos. However, I had spent a long time choosing settings and these were not restored.

What I am looking for is something that can clone my phone completely, so that I can get a new one, restore and effectively have the same phone.

If I can also use it to manage my phone from Windows - transfer files, change settings, etc. - then that is a bonus, but it is not a requirement.

Something free; something that someone has tried and tested.

Comment: Afraid you're looking for a Unicorn. Talking about "from Windows", the closest match would be *MyPhoneExplorer* (not being a Windows user, I cannot tell how "complete" those backups will be). Talking about "complete", *Titanium Backup* is the best choice (but not free, and not "from Windows", and requires root). Talking about "clone", this would only work between identical devices with the best candidate being a Nandroid backup (requires custom recovery). But all features in one tool: I happily learn I'm wrong, but IMHO that doesn't exist.

Comment: One thing I didn't mention: ADB backups. For details, see [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575) on our Android sister-site. Trouble is, without root you won't get access to everything (so the so-called "complete" ADB backup skips some things as well, e.g. SMS). In the end, to answer your last comment it is relevant whether your device is rooted or not. And I didn't play with "restoring system *configuration*", so I can't really answer that part.

Comment: Thanks. I will google & look for "best free Android manager", which I can't ask here. Do you know of something that will only backup/restore the config?